# templates urls in django

Tags: python, django

I have four templates with different links on my home.html but how can I make the links all functional with the correct URL, here's my home.html code

```
<div class="headernav">
    <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="faq">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </nav></ul>
</div>


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('department.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', include('about.urls')),
    url(r'^faq/', include('faq.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/about', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="headernav">
    <nav><ul>
        <li><a href="faq">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
        {% url 'blog' as blog_url %}
        <li><a href="{{ blog_url }}">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </nav></ul>
</div>


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('department.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'), name='blog'),  # note the name
    url(r'^about/', include('about.urls')),
    url(r'^faq/', include('faq.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/about', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Here I showed how to do the blog part, you can take it from there I think.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I appreciate